# websphere default page for ear not started

Tags: java, websphere, ear

Trying to set a default page or text for when an ear file is not started on websphere. The current error is either

Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /app/test.html
or

SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /app has not been defined.
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle www.mypage.com:443 has not been defined.

So far i've tried

```
<error-page>
<location>/general-error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Also have set this property without success

servers -> server types -> application servers -> server1 -> webcontainer settings ->webcontainer -> custom properties ->
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webgroupvhostnotfound

Comment: Please post the ear file structure.

Comment: There is no such thing as error page when ear is not started. You will have to define errorpage for error 500 on your web server in front of app server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two server entries that can control the display when an ear file is stopped. Add these and you will get a nice message rather than a default ugly one that user's will not understand.

Application servers > myserver > Web container > Custom properties

name: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.displayTextWhenNoErrorPageDefined

value: Server under maintenance, please try again later.

name: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webgroupvhostnotfound

value: Server under maintenance, please try again later.